# iOS VLCKit playerState .esAdded

Tags: ios, vlc, vlckit

VLCkit has several player states, what is the state .esAdded for? The others are self explanatory mainly. I haven't been able to find any details on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. esAdded happens when an Elementary Stream was added to your current playback. This occurs when either automatically an external subtitle file is discovered or if the client app adds external audio or subtitles streams. This can also happen when playing a DVB stream where the sender modifies the stream for instance when a show ends and a new show starts.